# Can I use the Adwaita theme in Unity without installing GNOME shell?

Tags: unity, 11.10, themes, gnome

I recently installed Ubuntu 11.10 (new install). I would like to use the Adwaita theme with Unity, but it seems that it is not available in the theme selection dialog. I know I get it there after installing gnome-shell, but is there a way to use Adwaita theme for Unity without installing gnome-shell?

Comment: Just so you know, in 11.10 if you install gnome-shell, you don't have to USE gnome-shell. (At the login screen you choose which shell to log in to.) Thus, you can install it and reap all the benefits (like Adwaita theme) and still use Unity.

Answer (score 2):

You can try running `sudo apt-get install gnome-themes-standard`, or you can just click this button:

[image: Install via the software center]

Or you can download this .deb which contains the theme also [link](https://launchpad.net/~ricotz/+archive/testing/+build/2811076)